# Angularjs routing is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

i have just started angularjs and came across the concept of routing i am doing a demo but its not working i don't know what I am doing wrong please help me out.I am doing it in MVC ASP.NET

Webapplicatoin3.js

```js
var app = angular.module('WebApplication3', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('CreateUser1Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.models = {
        helloAngular: 'I workssss!'
    };
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'New/CreateUser1'
        });
        
}]);
```

where in templateUrl "New" is the name of the controller and "CreateUser1" is action metohd

Home.cshtml

```html
<body ng-app="WebApplication3" ng-controller="CreateUser1Controller">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="models.helloAngular" />{{models.helloAngular}}
       
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/WebApplication3.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

CreateUser1.cshtml is not rendering in div ng-view.

CreateUser1.cshtml

```html
<h2>CreateUser1</h2>

<input type="text" ng-model="models.helloAngular" />
<h1>{{models.helloAngular}}</h1>
```

Comment: YOu need to add `@{Layout= null;}` in your `CreateUser1.cshtml` additionally you need to type `#/` in your **OR** write otherwise rule in `$routeProvider.otherwise`

Comment: "It's not working" is not sufficient to describe a problem. Do you get any errors in the console? Also "where in templateUrl "New" is the name of the controller and "CreateUser1" is action metohd" doesn't make any sense. `TemplateUrl` takes a _URL_ not the names of controllers.

Comment: @Ursus he is correct..controller's action will return view..

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry my bad, but still the question is not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PankajParkar i am following this link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par)

Comment: i don't know why it is not showing any error in the console there must be something wrong well I changed in templateUrl:"New/CreateUser1" to templateUrl:"/New/CreateUser1" and now it is working. Thanks alot i was stuck here for a long time thanks

Comment: @sam Please go ahead and add an answer..so that other could take help from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in WebApplication.js file
in templateUrl add "/" before New

update this

```js
 $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'New/CreateUser1'
        });
```

To this

```js
 $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/New/CreateUser1'
        });
```